# Qt Error request for member 'rowCount' in 'a', which is of non-class type 'QTableWidget*'

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

Code :

```
void MainWindow::add_test(QTableWidget* &a, QTableWidgetItem* &i1, QTableWidgetItem* &i2){

    int row = a.rowCount();
    a.setItem(row,0,i1);
    a.setItem(row,1,i2);
}
```

Now I get these errors :

- error: request for member 'rowCount' in 'a', which is of non-class type 'QTableWidget*'
- error: request for member 'setItem' in 'a', which is of non-class type 'QTableWidget*'
- error: request for member 'setItem' in 'a', which is of non-class type 'QTableWidget*'

What am I doing wrong? I just want to insert 2 items to the list (with a function).

*Edit: For those who wonder that it won't add a single item to the list, I forgot to insert a row in this function.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` is a reference to a *pointer* (`QTableWidget*`), so you should use the arrow (`operator ->`) instead of the dot (`operator .`) for accessing members of the pointed object:

```
int row = a->rowCount();
a->setItem(row,0,i1);
a->setItem(row,1,i2);
```